# How do I iteratate a List<string> passing back each string using a Func as a parameter?

Tags: c#, function, lambda, delegates

Given:

```
public void DoSomething(Func<List<string>, string> act){
   foreach(var thing in [TheListPassedIn]){
      act(thing);
   }
}
```

What's the proper code for getting addressibility to the list of the parameter named "act"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in your list and the function separately and create new list easily using Linq:

```
public List<string> ApplyFuncToEachItem(List<int> myList, Func<int, string> myFunc)
{
    return myList.Select(myFunc).ToList();
}
```

Example:

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0,10).ToList();
var myListOfStrings = ApplyFuncToEachItem(numbers, n => "bla " + n.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks Eagle Beak I think that's what I was looking to do "Use a Lamba on the calling side"...

Answer (score 1):

You don't pass a list of strings as parameter to the method. You actually pass a function which has a List as input parameter and returns a single string. There is no concrete list of strings involved.

Comment: Ok let's rephrase the question: An Action method is a callback, a Function goes one step further allowing an input and and output.  I want an external method to pass in a list and for each item in the list I want it to callback the method of choice. In particular I want to use Lambda's in the caller.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confising some of the things here. Your method does get a parameter, which is a transformation from a list to a string. There is not list here at all. The transformation does something, but you have to come up with the list in your DoSomething method, and probably call the transformation with your list as parameter. If this is not the workflow, then you probably defined your method the wrong way!